# How does JavaScript parse single line comments if it ignores newlines?

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet, javascriptcore

When you write JavaScript bookmarklets, you can't use `//` because the JavaScript code is treated as a single line. You have to use `/* ... */` instead. This doesn't make sense to me because you can use `//` in normal scripts even though the newlines are ignored.

In **section 2.3** of [The Definitive Guide](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596805531.do)

> JavaScript ignores spaces, tabs, and newlines that appear between
>   tokens in programs...

Then, in **section 2.5** of The Definitive Guide

> ...Any text between a // and the end of a line is treated as a comment
>   and is ignored by JavaScript...

Those statements seem contradictory.

According to **section 2.3**, the normal script is pretty much a single line of J.S as well since newlines are ignored. Can someone explain to me why `//` is possible in a normal script, but not in a bookmarklet?

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the most important part, ie *"... that appear between tokens ..."*

Comment: You can paste boomarklets [here](http://gutfullofbeer.net/escape.html) to url encode (and unencode) them.

Comment: The statement "JavaScript ignores spaces, tabs, and newlines" is wrong. They aren't ignored at all, they are essential to separate tokens, for automatic semi–colon insertion and to end single line comments that have following script. See [ECMA-262 §7.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.2): `White space characters are used to improve source text readability and to separate tokens (indivisible lexical units) from each other, but are otherwise insignificant`. Also, [Line terminators](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-7.3) are not whitespace.

Comment: @Phil I don't think I am. If you take var a = 5; <newline here> var b = 6; the newline appears between tokens but isn't ignored. I may be misunderstanding his definition of "ignored".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me emphasize part of the first quote

> JavaScript ignores spaces, tabs, and newlines that appear **between tokens in programs**

Programs are divided into tokens. For example, the following program

```
var x = "abc123";
```

has 5 tokens, namely, `var`, `x`, `=`, `"abc123"` and `;`. If you put more spaces between the tokens,

```
var    x     =    "abc123"       ;
```

it doesn't matter. But if you put a space inside of a token, then it can change the program. For example,

```
va r x = " a b c 12 3";
```

does not compile.

This difference is why the two statements are not contradictory. A comment is a single token that is ignored. If you put a newline in the middle of a comment, then you are not putting space in between tokens in a program, you are putting a space in the middle of a token.

A `//` comment ignores the rest of the content on the line. Since bookmarklets only contain 1 line, you would be commenting out everything after the `//`. In a normal script, you can have many lines, so you don't have the same problem.

If you are curious how this is specified, here's the [relevant part of the grammar in the ECMAScript 5 specification](http://es5.github.io/#x7.4):

```
SingleLineComment ::
   // SingleLineCommentCharsopt

SingleLineCommentChars ::
   SingleLineCommentChar SingleLineCommentCharsopt

SingleLineCommentChar ::
    SourceCharacter but not LineTerminator
```

Comment: Ah. This answer + @RobG's comment helped me understand a bit better. Newlines ARE and are NOT ignored at the same time. They are "ignored" in the sense that the appearance of newlines between tokens are irrelevant. They are not ignored in the sense that depending on where they appear the lexer may get different tokens (ie. comments). Correct?

Comment: Basically, I wish David Flanagan could have provided a bit more detail  in section 2.3 :D

Comment: @linstantnoodles Right, newlines are important in the lexing process. It's a little bit more complicated than one can simply say in a single sentence, because of automatic semicolon insertion, but you have the gist of it.

Answer (score 2):

Because a bookmarklet is a single line script, where as a regular script can be many lines.

Section 2.3 is a little vague. There are cases where white space does matter but the `//` just tells the processor to ignore the rest of that line.

If you used `//` in a bookmarklet, it would just stop processing right there.